# How can I make a stream of parent/child objects from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have a firestore database with a hierarchical relationship.  The "Parent" document has a collection ("children") of child objects.  I want to have a stream of Parent objections.  So if the parent changes in Fire store the stream should offer a new Parent object with all the children loaded.

The code below is what I am trying to achieve.  The problem is in the line marked "====> Problem", which in inserted into the code.

The compiler says : The return type 'List>' isn't a 'List', as defined by anonymous closure.dart(return_of_invalid_type_from_closure).

I don't know how to convert this stream to "map" call to an asyn call to get a List instead of a Future

Anyone know a good sample for hierarchical Firestore data in Flutter/Dart?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final parentsCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('parents');

Stream<List<Parent>> jots() {
  return parentsCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {

 //====================================================
        return snapshot.documents //  <===== Problem
 //====================================================
        .map((doc) async { 
          var parentEntity = await ParentEntity.fromSnapshot(doc);
          return Parent.fromEntity(parentEntity);
        }).toList();
  });
}

class Parent {
  final String id;
  final String data;
  final List<Child> children ;

  Parent(this.data, {
    String id, 
    List<Child> children
  })
      : this.id = id ?? '',
        this.children = children ?? List<Child>()
    ;

  static Parent fromEntity(ParentEntity entity) {
    var parent = Parent(
      entity.data,
      id: entity.id,
      children: entity.children.map((c)=>Child.fromEntity(c))
    );
    return parent;
  }
}

class Child {
  final String id;
  final String label;

  Child(this.label, {String id})
      : this.id = id ?? '';

  static Child fromEntity(ChildEntity entity) {
    var child = Child(
      entity.label,
      id: entity.id,
    );
    return child;
  }
}

class ParentEntity {
  final String id;
  final String data;
  final List<ChildEntity> children;

  ParentEntity( this.id, this.data, this.children );

  static Future<ParentEntity> fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
    var children = await _childrenFromSnapshot(snapshot);
    return ParentEntity( 
      snapshot.documentID, 
      snapshot.data['data'], 
      children
    );
  }

  static Future<List<ChildEntity>> _childrenFromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
    var childCollection = snapshot.reference.collection("children");
    QuerySnapshot docs = await childCollection.getDocuments();
    return docs.documents.map((doc) {
      return ChildEntity( doc.documentID, doc.data["label"]);
    });
  }
}

class ChildEntity {
  final String id;
  final String label;

  ChildEntity( this.id, this.label );

  static ChildEntity fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return ChildEntity( 
      snapshot.documentID,
      snapshot.data['label']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
Stream<List<Parent>> jots2() {
  return parentsCollection.snapshots().asyncMap((snapshot) async {
    return Future.wait(snapshot.documents.map((doc) async {
      var parentEntity = await ParentEntity.fromSnapshot(doc);
      return Parent.fromEntity(parentEntity);
    }).toList());
  });
}
```

The trick is to use `asyncMap` (which is like map, but async) and `Future.wait` (which waits for all Futures to complete) to asynchronously process QuerySnapshot.

Few notes:

- you're probably missing `.toList()` after all `.map`
- using this method your Stream **won't emit** new value if only value of the children is changed, but it does send updated children if you update the parent
- because this way you always read full children collection of the parent this may impact your Firestore usage as it is per document basis

You also asked for "good" sample. Unfortunately - it depends on your data and app. Firebase made a [whole page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data) about structuring data. Sometimes it is better to avoid subcollections, sometimes it's not.

It seems that in your case having your "children" as data field (children2) rather than subcollection make more sense, but I don't exactly know what are you creating.

[image: Firestore panel]

Answer (score 0):

you're declaring `Stream<List<Parent>>` as the type, but `.map()` in combo with `.toList()` is returning `List<dynamic>`.  you need to declare the type on the map:

```
return Future.wait(snapshot.documents.map<Parent>((doc) async {
```